# jquery loop and compare values

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use jqueries each loop in this form to dissolve hyperlinks?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var toExclude =['http://www.google.com', 'http://example'];
    $.each(toExclude, function(key, value) {

    $("a[href='+value+']").replaceWith(function(){
        var matches = value.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);
        var domain = matches && matches[1];
        return domain;
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by `dissolve`?

Comment: on match all a href should be removed and just the a href text should be returned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("a[href='+value+']")
```

should be:

```
$("a[href='"+value+"']")
```

Also you probably want to change only the `href` property => use the [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$("a[href='"+value+"']").attr("href", function() {
    // do your replace and return the new value of the href
    ...
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on this Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Could you show your code? Could you show a http://jsfiddle.net sample illustrating your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
var toExclude = ['www.goo.com','www.dgoo.com'];

$.each(toExclude, function(i,e)
       {

           $("a[href^='"+e+"']").each(function (i,e) {$(e).replaceWith($(e).attr('href'));});
       }
​);
       ​
```

Comment: @lgt I'm supposing you want to replace each `<a href='foo'>bar</a>` with simply `foo`

Comment: yes that I would like to achieve if the a href is matching with one the values from array

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href="'+value+'"]').attr("href", function() {
    // do your replace and return the new value of the href
```

A little change in quote signs.. this allows you to also do

```
$('a[href$="'+value+'"]').attr("href", function() {
    // do your replace and return the new value of the href
```

and

```
$('a[href^="'+value+'"]').attr("href", function() {
    // do your replace and return the new value of the href
```

to match links beggining and ending with **value**